# Stopping animation and starting a new one

Tags: d3.js, timer

I'm building a visualization which contains data per 15 minutes per day, so I update the viz according to that.

I've two buttons, one to start one random day viz and the other one to stop it and start another random day viz.

The problem is that when I click in the start another day button, the visualization starts updating the info really quickly, seems that the previous timer is still going on. I tried to find a way to solve it but didn't come to a solution.

html buttons:

```
<input name="updateButton" 
                 type="button" 
                value="Another day" 
 onclick="playAnimation(500)" />

 <input name="updateButton" 
                 type="button" 
                value="Start" 
 onclick="playAnimation(500)" />
```

Animation d3js code:

```
function playAnimation(speed) {

    var interval_speed = speed;
    var dates = getAllDays('04/01/2016', '07/31/2016');
    random_day = dates[Math.floor(Math.random() * dates.length)];


    var fname = 'mapped_molinetes_agg_per15_' + random_day[0] + '.csv';
    d3.csv(fname, function(molinetes)
    {   
        var timeIntervals = getUniqueValuesArray(molinetes, 'DESDE'); //TODO: sort?
        var timeout;
        var period = timeIntervals.shift();
        function timer() {
            var filtered_molinetes = molinetes.filter(function(d){ 
              return d.DESDE === period; 
            });
            update(filtered_molinetes, period, random_day);

            period = timeIntervals.shift();
            if (period){
                timeout = setTimeout(timer, interval_speed);
            }
        }
        stopAnimation(timer);
        timeout = setTimeout(timer, interval_speed);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to clear the timeout before you set a new one, see [clearTimeout on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout)

The problem is that once you trigger the async timeout calls, you never stop them. They continue until there is no `period` left.

Look at this problem:

```
timeout = window.setTimeout(() => console.log('async call'), 1000)
timeout = window.setTimeout(() => console.log('I am still faster'), 500)
```

When you select a new date, take your `timeout` reference and stop it with `window.clearTimeout(timeout)`.